# How to index a field for both numeric and text search

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to enable both numberic and full-text search for a field.

I need the two ways to search the field for different scenarios.

How can I index the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always make use of [fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#multi-fields) for such use cases. Lets say the field name is `field1`. Below is how you can define it for indexing it in different ways:

```
   "field1": {
      "type": "integer",
      "fields": {
        "textval": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54606107/handling-both-exact-and-partial-search-on-the-same-search-string#54606959) for understanding more on fields.

Comment: Thanks Nishant! What if I want to add another type "keyword" for aggregation? That is, it should have different types: integer, text, and keyword. I searched through multi-fields examples in ES but can only find at most 2 types.

Comment: Updated my answer for the same